# does this real sequence of integrals converge?

Tags: real-analysis

If $(f_n)$ is a sequence of functions in $C[0,1]$ and $f_n \rightarrow f$ uniformly in [0,1] then $ \int_0^{1-\frac{1}{n}} f_n \rightarrow \int_0^1 f$ . True or False? I think it's false, but I'm having trouble finding a counterexample.

Comment: $\{f_n\}$ should be uniformly bounded by some $M$, therefore $\int_{1-1/n}^1\lvert f_n\rvert\le M/n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:
$$
\int_0^{1-1/n} |f(x) - f_n(x)| dx + \int_{1-1/n}^1 |f(x)-0|dx 
$$
$$
\leq \sup_n |f-f_n| (1-\frac1n) + \sup|f|\frac1n
$$
$$
\to 0\cdot 1+\sup |f| \cdot 0.
$$
$$
= 0
$$

Comment: Thanks....so I was wrong about it being false!